# Allocating memory for structures in c

Tags: c, heap-memory

```
struct data{
char *key;
char *fname;
char *lname;
char *grade;
struct data *next;
};


 newnode = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
 strcpy(newnode->lname,lname);
 strcpy(newnode->grade,grade);
 strcpy(newnode->key,key);
 strcpy(newnode->fname,fname);
 newnode->next=NULL;
```

So i was working on hashtables. The above code crashes while

```
struct data *newnode;
newnode = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
newnode->lname=(char*)malloc(strlen(lname)+1);
newnode->fname=(char*)malloc(strlen(fname)+1);
newnode->grade=(char*)malloc(strlen(grade)+1);
newnode->key=(char*)malloc(strlen(key)+1);

strcpy(newnode->lname,lname);
strcpy(newnode->grade,grade);
strcpy(newnode->key,key);
strcpy(newnode->fname,fname);
newnode->next=NULL;
```

this code seems to run. Why is that? As far as i understand i've already allocated memory for my struct in the heap. Why would i have to do it for each object specifically? Is there something else im missing? Cause i really don't understand why the bottom example would work.

Comment: We need more detail. Which line does it crash on, for instance?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].

Comment: As an aside: `strdup()` is a nicer way to duplicate strings than  `malloc()/strcpy()` combinations.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The drawback is that `strdup` is not a standard function. Though I don't know any C compiler or system that doesn't come with it.

Comment: You will also want to look at the obligatory "there is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`", it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) .

Comment: Just because something isn't in the C standard doesn't mean it's not useful.

Comment: `strdup` is in POSIX and available also in Windows, so it is quite portable for desktop programs. When it fails to compile on some obscure platform, it is easy to provide an emulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `newnode = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data))`, you allocate memory only for `struct data`, which is a set of pointers, but you do not allocate any memory for that where these pointers are pointing to and where you will copy your strings to. So you have to allocate memory for each string separately, either by using `malloc` as in the second part of your question, or by using `strdup`, which does `malloc` and `strcpy` in one command:

```
struct data{
char *key;
char *fname;
char *lname;
char *grade;
struct data *next;
};


 newnode = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
 newnode->lname = strdup(lname);
 newnode-> grade = strdup(grade);
 newnode-> key = strdup(key);
 newnode-> fname = strdup(fname);
 newnode->next=NULL;
```

It's worth noting that `strdup` requires a string as input, i.e. a pointer that is not `NULL` and that points to a `\0`-terminated sequence of characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot both to you and @SomeProgrammerDude . That makes sense

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

you only allocate memory for the actual *structure*. But since the structure contains pointers, you need to make those pointers point somewhere valid. The single `malloc` call doesn't know anything about the contents of the structure, or how much extra memory it should allocate for all the pointers.

If, for example, you declare a single normal pointer variable you would not expect to be able to just use it as a destination for a `strcpy` call without allocating memory, would you?

Answer (score 0):

When you `malloc` a structure with `char *` inside it doesn't point anywhere (at least is `NULL`) so you've to `malloc` it as a normal sequence of characters also because you **must** know the size of the destination string. You can do it in your way using `malloc` and `strcpy` or just `strdup`.

Comment: `strncpy()` is terrible for most uses - you need to jump through hoops to ensure that the destination is properly terminated.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If the source string is properly terminated and you use strncpy in the right way it improves security and robustness of you code avoiding buffer overflows.

Comment: @BetaRunner, strncpy has it's uses, but not as a "safe" version of strcpy. Sadly it's a much misunderstood function. Also the buffer returned by malloc may contain garbage, so there's no guarantee that the pointers in the stuct are NULL. Most likely they are not.

Comment: @BetaRunner: Microsoft [disallows `strncpy()` in their own code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx) (and newer MSVC compilers warn about it by default for everyone) because of documented problems in its use.  And here's [a quote from Linus Torvalds about `strncpy()`](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/strncpy.html): "`strncpy()` is a frigging disaster when it comes to '\0', in many ways. We should probably disallow using `strncpy()`"

Comment: You're right guys, I read a lot about it now and I agree with you.